# Rails: Model can be one of several types - How to store it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

First, sorry for bad title, couldn't come up with something more descriptive.

I have a user model.  I'd like to set a type for that user which can be one of 5 options; doesn't matter what the options are, any strings will do.  I'd like to be able to search based on these options.

I think I have the following options:

1. Added field as string to model with index
2. Create a user_type table and do belongs_to/has_many relationship
3. Save type as integer and map integer to a constant defined in user model, with string value (no idea how to do this though)

What's the **Rails Way** to solve this problem that will meet the following goals:

- Searchable
- Maintainable
- Readable

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked into using [single table inheritance](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=3815), with the drop down feeding the user's tpye?

Comment: @Jimmy Thanks for the link. From the comments, it seems my option 2 is the way to go.  I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really does depend on your meaning of 'type'. If it's a role (such as "administrator", "moderator", "user", etc.) where a given user **can only be of one type**, you can just do it with a string column - no need for a separate table.

If the user can be multiple types simultaneously ("newly-registered", "male", "student", "blogger"), **where the user type works more like a tag**, then your `user_type` table will do the job.

Comment: The user can only be of one type, but I would like to be able to find all users of a certain type, so it's kind of a tag.  Many users can have the same tag.

Comment: If you want to be able to find all users of a certain type, then you just search on the column, either via a `scope` (or `named_scope` in Rails2), or do a simple `User.find_by_role('administrator')` (where `role` is the name of the column in this example), which will give you all users of that type. You can search on any column in any table, and filter by what's in it.

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense and looks easier than the two table approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with option #2, that will let you dynamically add user types without touching code. If in the future, you want to let a user be more than different types simultaneously, check out [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many)